# Resource Identifiers

Tags: api, rest, uuid, opensearch

I was reading this [guideline](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Cloud_APIs_REST_Style_Guide#Identifiers) about resource identifiers and I'm not sure how a client would be able to navigate to the resource just having the entry point URL and the identifier.

How does the client find out the URL structure to be used to fetch the resource? URI template? Maybe a search feature that uses OpenSearch? How do you usually solve this?

Let me know of any examples of REST APIs that solved this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The client doesn't find URL structures but follows (relative) links.